# Python long listing directory (ls -l), ls *

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to to a `ls -l` from python, to check for the last modification date of a file.

`os.listdir` doesn't show the long list format.
`subprocess.call` shows the format, but actually prints it, and returns 0. I want to be able to put it in a variable. Any ideas ?

Also, I tried

```
subprocess.call("ls","*.py")
```

which answers

```
ls: cannot access *.py: No such file or directory
```

it works with `shell=True`, but if someone could explain why it doesn't work without it, I'll appreciate. If you know how to make it work, even better.

Comment: Why in the world would you shell out to do that rather than just using `os.path.getmtime()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't work without `shell=True` because the `*` is a shell expansion character - going from `*.py` to a list of files ending in `.py` is a function performed by the shell itself, not `ls` or `python`.

If you want to get the output of a command invoked via `subprocess`, you should use `subprocess.check_output()` or `subprocess.Popen`.

```
ls_output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l'])
```

Comment: Of course, an even better way is not to call `ls` at all, and instead use `os.listdir()` and `os.stat()` (or the utility functions in `os.path` and the `glob` module.)

Comment: I agree. But since the question was specifically about subprocess, I figure I should at least answer that for anyone else who comes across the question.

Comment: Sure, but recommending the actual right way of doing things as well is more helpful, for the OP and for anyone who tries to do the same thing.

Comment: I was in need to get the response of a process call by `subprocess`. Even the right way of using `ls` with `subprocess` is using `os.listdir()`, Amber showed me that how I can get the output of a process except from `ls` like `python myfile.py`.

Answer (score 2):

With nice formatting:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-lh']).decode('utf-8'))
```